# Correct use of memcpy in C

Tags: c, memcpy

I am attempting to copy the content of an error object from a deque, but when
I check the copied content, it is not correct.

```
typedef struct ER_OBJECT
{
    uint8 error_type;

    union
    {
        uint32 number;
        char *message;
    } error;

} ER_OBJECT;

void er_copy(DE_LIST *deque, ER_OBJECT *object)
{
    ER_OBJECT *marker;

    marker = er_get_first_object(deque);

    memcpy(object, marker, sizeof(*marker));
}
```

Everything up to and including the function `er_get_first_object` works as
intended, ie I can examine the content of marker and it is correct. This leads me to believe that the problem lies with memcpy.

If I create a second pointer to an ER_OBJECT called marker2, and use memcpy to
copy the content of marker into marker2, everything works fine. It is only when I
attempt to copy the content of marker to the external object that an error
occurs.

Would someone be so kind as to point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks ok. Maybe you have messed up your heap *elsewhere*. Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Indeed, it looks more like the memory buffer that is `object` hasn't been allocated properly or something similar.

Comment: How are you examining the contents of marker, object, and marker2?  in a debugger?  Maybe you can post the memory dumps.  do you look at the contents of object before and after `er_copy()` returns?

Comment: Can you add the code that is calling `er_copy()`?

Comment: Have you allocated any space to copy the object into?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey Bingo - I had declared a pointer to an ER_OBJECT in the calling code, but had not allocated the space using `malloc`. Many thanks for judicious use of the cluebat.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the posted code is correct.

I say "unfortunately" because this means that the problem is somewhere else in your program.  I suggest using additional tools, such as Mudflap and Valgrind.

1. If using GCC, compile with `-fmudflap`.  This requires the mudflap libraries to be installed.
2. Run with Valgrind.

The tools do overlap in purpose somewhat, but there are some errors which only one of the two tools will catch.